# How do i sum all values in a specific row in a table and then display it?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database where i have different rows with different numeric values. I want to sum all the values in all of the rows in the table and display the total sum inside an html code.

```
div class="bottom-section">
    <h2><?php echo $summer; ?></h2>
    <span>You have sold for this much.</span>
</div>
```

```
<?php
    $summer = ("SELECT sum(kr) FROM $table");
?>
```

What is displayed in the page is this
[image]

Comment: Because your `$summer` is just string, it does not magically executes by itself. Use PDO or mysqli for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**first connect with your database using this **

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","DATABASE_NAME");
```

**then write this code**

```
$data=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT sum(kr) FROM $table");
```

**Answer is stored in in `$data`**

Comment: Get this error when trying to echo it: Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in /var/www/html/adminpanel.php on line 32

Comment: With some mixing and trixing i got it to work with your code:) Thank you.

Comment: When i echoed it i needed to use: while ($row = $data->fetch_assoc()) {
 $vis = $row['sum(kr)']."kr i dag";